# Auxiliary movement in AAVE

Tags: grammar, african-american-vernacular-english

My question is inspired by the question of [why "So do I"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/why-do-you-say-so-do-i/65195#65195). Usually I have no problem figuring out what to do for AAVE (African American Vernacular English), but in this case, I am confused, because AAVE allows more than one auxiliary, and has different movement rules.

For the case of one auxiliary,

- She be working
- be he working too?
- He be working too?

I am not sure if the second or third is preferred.

- She be working.
- So be he.(?)
- So he be. (?)

I think "So be he" is correct, not "So he be."

How about double auxiliaries?

- He done been sleeping
- So I done been.
- So done I been.
- So done been I

Which is considered correct? I think it's the third "So done been I", but I am not sure.

This pair I am pretty sure about:

- He done been working
- Done he been working?

For others, I have intuition

- I'm a-gonna fly it
- So am I a-gonna.

But this one confuses me:

- He stay working
- So stay I(?)
- So I stay(?)
- So do I stay(?)

Which is it?

The last one is

- He done been staying working
- So I done been staying.
- So done I been staying.
- So done been I staying.
- So done been staying I.

Which one? I think it's the second, maybe the first. Not sure.

Any insights?

Comment: Should post a copy on linguisticsSE as well.

Comment: Yes, but only native speakers of AAVE should attempt to answer here. And there are local lects to consider -- AAVE is not all that standard across the country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I am not a native AAVE speaker, I have many friends who are. Mostly from the Eastern and Central US. and I am quite sure I know them well enough to recognize their speech patterns.
First,  I believe they would nearly always add the "*too*" to the end of these sentences, so I will phrase them that way here.  The accepted phrasings are as follows:

> She be workin'.  *He be workin' too.* and *So be he.*
>     ("*So he be.*" would be used to express surprise upon verifying that he was indeed working.)
>   
>   He done been sleepin'.  *So I done been too*.
>   He done been workin'.  *He done been workin'?* (This is just turned right back as a question.)
>   I'm a gonna fly it. *So I'm a gonna too.*
>   He stay workin'. *So I stay(s) too.*  (There is often an 's' added to 'stay' here)
>   He done been stayin' workin'.  *So I done been stayin' too.*